# Auto-populate Column Values between Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula, auto-populate

I have a newbie question. I am collecting Google Form Responses in Form 1 in this format in Sheet 1:

| Timestamp | Name | Preferred Choice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/9/2022 16:09:24 | John | A |
| 2/9/2022 16:09:24 | Sally | B |

I want to auto insert new rows for two similar columns in Sheet 2:

| Name | Preferred Choice |
| --- | --- |
| John | A |
| Sally | B |

If a new response like this comes in:

| Timestamp | Name | Preferred Choice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/9/2022 16:09:24 | Tom | C |

It should auto populate in Sheet 2 without any intervention.

Expected:

| Name | Preferred Choice |
| --- | --- |
| John | A |
| Sally | B |
| Tom | C |

Can I check how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The new response might come to Sheet1.

So in this case it is simple.

```
='incoming Answers'!C2
```

If you don't want to update the "old rows" you can copy the formulas and paste them as values.

I guess one can do this with "Get and Transform" (Power Query) as well.

[image]